# Combination of anonymous and windows authentication on sharepoint 2007 web

Tags: 2007, development, authentication

is it possible to enable anonymous access only for a specific library? The script library should have an anonymous access whereus the page library should use the windows authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, definately is possible.  In fact, as far as I know, the default behaviour when you enable Anonymous on a Wep App is to specifically deny anonymous access to all libraries.

this means you need to apply permissions to enable anonymous access for your libraries - by extension just don't enable this for the library that you are concerned about.

Comment: Agree, but still its throwing 401 for anonymous users and 200 for the authenticated users...any clues.